# Expression to show specific attribute of feature within (aggregate?)

Tags: qgis, expression, within, aggregate

I simply want to get a specific attribute (f.e. as label or default value in form) of a feature within another feature. Aggregate could do the job but it don't.

Hard for me to write it down, so let me explain on the screenshot below: All polygons are in the same layer. The green polygon is labeled with the expression:

```
aggregate('SameLayer','concatenate', to_string("Number"), intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)))
```

That works fine so it tells me, I'm on the right way! All intersection features (101, 102, 103) are written to the label (or later to the attribute form). Since I just want the number of the the polygon, where the green one complete fits within, I changed 'intersects' to 'within' (or 'contains') and expect as result: 102  - but it don't!

```
aggregate('SameLayer','concatenate', to_string("Number"), within($geometry, geometry(@parent)))
```

The reason is, the green polygon touches with 3 of its sides, the parent polygon. If I draw the polygon complete within the parent, the expression works.

I wonder what could be the right geometry function in my case, and if Aggregate is the right way to solve that trivial task?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if something is off with how [`aggregate()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#aggregate) handles geometric predicates (I am using QGIS 3.12.2)

I tried using the DE-9!M representation - according to [`relate()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#relate) the relationship between the green polygon and 102 was `'2FF11F212'`, so I used that to test the relationship instead of [`within()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#id319), but it kept returning an empty string (or `NULL` since the green polygon itself has a null value for `"Number"`).

Eventually I got it to work with: `aggregate('SameLayer','concatenate', to_string("Number"), relate($geometry,geometry(@parent),'212F11FF2'))`

But, perhaps a crucial difference is that I also managed to get the expression to work with [`contains()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#contains), so maybe our geometries are not the same?? See if the above works for you...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this expression that uses the [`overlay_within()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-within) function introduced in QGIS 3.16: `array_to_string(overlay_within(@layer, "number"))`

*Screenshot: I have 3 polygons (101,102,103) and a fourth on the same layer that lies within polygon 102 and has a `NULL` value for the attribute `"number"`: I use this empty value for a rule based label with the expression from above:

[image]